# Image uploading on ck editor and displaying the image on CMS page

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, ckeditor4.x

I am developing CMS pages on my laravel application using the CK Editor. The issue I am facing is that when I upload the image in ck editor and save its html in database the image is saved like the following

```
    <figure class="easyimage easyimage-full"><img alt="" src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/d0765b76-6046-46da-a3e7-dafddb2bd85e" width="500">
         <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
```

However the image is saved in my public directory but I cannot see the image on the cms page. I think there is some kind of configuration issue in ckeditor which I cannot identify. I want the src of the image to the path where I have stored the image. Anyone who can guide me through this.